# Is there a way to find TOP X records with grouped data?

Tags: t-sql, sybase, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working with a Sybase 12.5 server and I have a table defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable(
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SomeName] varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (GroupID,DateStamp)
)
```

I want to be able to list, per [GroupID], only the latest X records by [DateStamp].  The kicker is X > 1, so plain old MAX() won't cut it.  I'm assuming there's a wonderfully nasty way to do this with cursors and what-not, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way without that stuff.

I know I'm missing something blatantly obvious and I'm gonna kick myself for not getting it, but .... I'm not getting it.  Please help.

Is there a way to find TOP X records, but with grouped data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the online manual, Sybase 12.5 supports `WINDOW` functions and `ROW_NUMBER()`, though their syntax differs from standard SQL slightly.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT SP.*
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (windowA ORDER BY [DateStamp] DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM SomeTable
    WINDOW windowA AS (PARTITION BY [GroupID])
) AS SP
WHERE SP.RowNum <= 3
ORDER BY RowNum DESC;
```

I don't have an instance of Sybase, so I haven't tested this. I'm just synthesizing this example from the doc.

---

I made a mistake.  The doc I was looking at was Sybase SQL Anywhere 11.  It seems that Sybase ASA does not support the `WINDOW` clause at all, even in the most recent version.

Here's another query that could accomplish the same thing.  You can use a self-join to match each row of SomeTable to all rows with the same GroupID and a later DateStamp.  If there are three or fewer later rows, then we've got one of the top three.

```
SELECT s1.[GroupID], s1.[Foo], s1.[Bar], s1.[Baz]
FROM SomeTable s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeTable s2
  ON s1.[GroupID] = s2.[GroupID] AND s1.[DateStamp] < s2.[DateStamp]
GROUP BY s1.[GroupID], s1.[Foo], s1.[Bar], s1.[Baz]
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
ORDER BY s1.[DateStamp] DESC;
```

Note that you *must* list the same columns in the `SELECT` list as you list in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Basically, all columns from `s1` that you want this query to return.

Comment: Many thanks.  I'll try this when I get into work Friday and see if it works.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'."  I'll keep trying, though.

Comment: My apologies, I think I led you on a wild goose chase.  I've added a different solution above.

Comment: Ugh, not your doing, but the table I need to query is relatively large (~500K rows) and appears not to have the necessary indexes.  Queries simply timeout.  However, what you've posted makes sense.  I think this is what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, I won't be able to use it.  Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Yes, without indexes appropriate to the queries you need to run, a database of any nontrivial size is practically unusable.  You should use `set showplan on` to guide you to create the best indexes.  See chapter 36 of *ASE Performance and Tuning Guide*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's quite an unscalable way!

```
SELECT GroupID, DateStamp, SomeName
FROM SomeTable ST1
WHERE X < 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM SomeTable ST2 
     WHERE ST1.GroupID=ST2.GroupID AND ST2.DateStamp > ST1.DateStamp)
```

**Edit** Bill's solution is vastly preferable though.